# Parsing JSON with Jackson return null

Tags: java, json, parsing, jersey-client, google-books

I'm training my self on java using API. The subject of my exercise is to ask google books API in order to take some infos about books. I use Jersey as a client and Jackson to parse the JSON.

My problem is that when i run the `JerseyVolumeGet()` , the response is this one :

```
Volume{title='null', numberOfPages=null, author='null'}
```

Why ? Where is my mistake ? I suspect i get wrong when parsing the JSON but don't see where exactly..

Here my getClass ( the search url is barcoded , it's not a problem for me)

```
public class JerseyVolumeGet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Client client = Client.create();

            WebResource webResource = client
                    .resource("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=1984");

            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                    .get(ClientResponse.class);

            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Noob you Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatus());
            }

            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            // read from file, convert it to user class
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Volume volume = mapper.readValue(output, Volume.class);


            // display to console
            System.out.println(volume);


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

Here the JSON result of my query :

```
{
 "kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 641,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "RY8yQWeDVFYC",
   "etag": "Lf0P50PVz9c",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/RY8yQWeDVFYC",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "(1984).",
    "subtitle": "",
    "authors": [
     "Guy Serbat",
     "Jean Taillardat",
     "Gilbert Lazard"
    ],
    "publisher": "Peeters Publishers",
    "publishedDate": "1984-01-01",
    "description": "(Peeters 1984)",
    "industryIdentifiers": [
     {
      "type": "ISBN_10",
      "identifier": "2904685030"
     },
     {
      "type": "ISBN_13",
      "identifier": "9782904685033"
     }
    ],
    "readingModes": {
     "text": false,
     "image": true
    },
    "pageCount": 280,
    "printType": "BOOK",
    "categories": [
     "Language Arts & Disciplines"
    ],
    "contentVersion": "1.1.1.0.preview.1",
    "imageLinks": {
     "smallThumbnail": "http://bks9.books.google.fr/books?id=RY8yQWeDVFYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
     "thumbnail": "http://bks9.books.google.fr/books?id=RY8yQWeDVFYC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
    },
    "language": "fr",
    "previewLink": "http://books.google.fr/books?id=RY8yQWeDVFYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=1984&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
    "infoLink": "http://books.google.fr/books?id=RY8yQWeDVFYC&dq=1984&hl=&source=gbs_api",
    "canonicalVolumeLink": "http://books.google.fr/books/about/1984.html?hl=&id=RY8yQWeDVFYC"
   },
   "saleInfo": {
    "country": "FR",
    "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
    "isEbook": false
   },
   "accessInfo": {
    "country": "FR",
    "viewability": "PARTIAL",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicDomain": false,
    "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
    "epub": {
     "isAvailable": false
    },
    "pdf": {
     "isAvailable": false
    },
    "webReaderLink": "http://books.google.fr/books/reader?id=RY8yQWeDVFYC&hl=&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&source=gbs_api",
    "accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE",
    "quoteSharingAllowed": false
   },
   "searchInfo": {
    "textSnippet": "(Peeters 1984)"
   }
  },
more items...
}
```

Then , i've a `Volume.class` like that :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Volume {
    @JsonProperty("title")
    String title;
    @JsonProperty("pageCount")
    Integer pageCount;
    @JsonProperty("authors")
    String authors;

getters , setters and toString..
```

Comment: You need to model the wrapping object structures. As you can see in the JSON, you have an outer object with an array of `"items"`, and each item object contains a `"volumeInfo"` property. Because of this, Jackson can't map the full structure to your `Volume` class directly - you need to model the parent objects as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to model the full JSON structure, something like this:

```
public class BookData {
    String kind;
    Integer totalItems;
    List<Item> items;
}

public class Item {
    String kind;
    String id;
    //...
    Volume volumeInfo;
}
```

Then you can use `ObjectMapper` to read the `BookData`:

```
BookData bookData = new ObjectMapper().readValue(output, BookData.class);
```

And pull out the `Volume` info from each `Item` in the `BookData`.

Comment: Thx , gonna work on . So annotations like :  @JsonProperty("title")
    String title; aren't realy necessary ?

Comment: No, not if the field name in the class matches the property name in the data.